# Why am I not able to get access to the kernel on Ubuntu with the following code?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I tried the following command but it's not working:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Post any error messages you're getting exactly.

Comment: invalid operation source image 3.5.0-23-generic

Comment: Read `man apt-get` - the second word in the command needs to be something like `install` IIRC.

Comment: @ultrasawblade SOurce is an operation to downlload the source

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that you do not have source [URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You should add a line like this (adapt it to your specific Ubuntu version):

```
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and try installing the sources again.